# LassoCV vs RidgeCV in Python -- why are their default number of folds different?

Tags: cross-validation, lasso, ridge-regression

In https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html, it says that `LassoCV` defaults to 5 folds.

In https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html, it says that `RidgeCV` defaults to leave one out ($n$ folds).

Why are the two different? Is there any theoretical or practical justification for not using LOOCV for Lasso?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two possible contributing reasons

1. The non-smoothness of the lasso makes some statisticians nervous about leave-one-out operations (even though there are now [results for the lasso](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-014-5438-z))
2. For ridge regression the LOOCV can be computed rapidly using the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula for single-row updates. For the lasso, you need to actually refit the model, which is slow if you do it $n$ times.